# Как добавлять инкремент(i) в css класс на pug(он же бывший jade)?

Tags: html, jade, pug

На нативном javascript это было-бы примерно следующим образом:

HTML:

```
<div class="btns"></div>
<div class="btns"></div>
```

Js:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btns');

for(i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
  buttons.classList.add('btn_' +i);
}
```

Pug:

```
- var modalList = [{
    title: "Многокамерная съемка", 
    posterImage: "content/video.jpg",
    description: 'Мы используем камеры Panasonic, Sony, Blackmagic, Go Pro.Съемка на несколько камер с возможностью прямой трансляции, проекторы, плазменные панели. Онлайн трансляции в сети Интернет: 720р, 1080р, 4К.В нашем арсенале мультироторы для съемки верхних планов с 3-х осевой стабилизацией и возможностью передачи сигнала на пульт видеоинженеров (с дальнейшей трансляцией на экраны или в сеть).Кинематографические краны и тележки обеспечивают подвижность картинки и необходимую плавность кадра. Тросовая гиростабилизированная система подвеса с длиной кабельной линии до 100 метров позволяет снимать большие спортивные мероприятия и концерты непосредственно над зрителями.Благодаря оптическим удлинителям сигнала работа операторов проходит на значительном удалении от пультовой. Изображение передается в формате высокой четкости.'
 },
    {title: "blabla"}
];


    mixin modal-tackles(tackles)
        .modal.modal-contact.fade.tackles__modal_(здесь должен быть инкремент)(tabindex="-1", role="dialog",  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel")
            .modal-dialog(role="document")
                .modal-content
                    .modal-header
                        span= tackles.title
                        button.close(type="button",data-dismiss="modal", aria-label="Close")
                            span(aria-hidden="true") x
                    .modal-body

    for tackles in modalList
        +modal-tackles(tackles)
```

Comment: а как сейчас генерируется html?

Comment: [Вот документация](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html)

Comment: @ Хангелды Илебаев, читать я умею, спасибо, мне на примере нужно

Comment: @Grundy, если вы о том, что происходит у меня в шаблонизаторе - то я внес правки в вопрос)

Comment: да про это. Куда ты тут хочешь добавить индексы? а вижу

Comment: @Grundy, ".tackles__modal_ +index"

Comment: @Grundy, чтобы в итоге получился css класс что-то типа tackles__modal_1, tackles__modal_ 2 или tackles__modal_0, tackles__modal_1

Comment: @Grundy, т.е в цикле сначала завести переменную? что-то типа var  index =  i++;

Comment: нет, минуту, напишу ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `for` в данном случае лучше использовать [`each`](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html#each), так как он позволяет получить индекс текущей итерации.

Далее этот индекс нужно передать в mixin.

Так как классы не поддерживают интерполяцию, класс, который надо собирать динамически нужно перенести в атрибуты.

В итоге должно получиться что-то такое:

```
for tackles, index in modalList
    +modal-tackles(tackles, index)
```

И в mixin:

```
mixin modal-tackles(tackles, index)
    .modal.modal-contact.fade(class=`tackles__modal_${index}`, tabindex="-1", role="dialog",  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel")
```

Comment: елки иголоки, делал так уже только я писал "class=`tackles__modal_ +index" вместо: "class=`tackles__modal_${index}" , АТ ДУШЫ)

Comment: ну вообще говоря, твой вариант тоже должен был работать, возможно забыл передавать сам индекс в миксин, а и синтаксис неверный, должно было быть как-то так:`(class="tackles__modal_"+index`

Comment: http://dropmefiles.com/fAoRz

Comment: @GoodNew5, ага, в вызове mixin - не передаешь index, поэтому внутри его он undefined